# Generating a directory folder structure from database

Tags: c#, database-design, logic

Finding myself in loopie loops. I have a database table that defines a directory folder structure with potentially infinite number of subfolders.

The end result folder structure should look like this, but the logic should allow this structure requirement to change:

[image: expected result structure]

Given this data for the above folder structure:

[image: input data]

The most important fields are `id` and `pid`. `pid` of `NULL` represents the top level folders (Email, TM Applications, TM Disputes). All other folders are subfolders which go down 3 levels stored in `level_count` field. Not sure I really need `level_count` field though. I've been trying to make the logic as "flexible" as possible. `pid` defines a folder's immediate parent:

[image: Example queries for distinct folder levels]

My current solution is not good enough because it doesn't handle the *"infinite"* number of levels, it only supports three levels. I prefer not to have to know the number of levels.

I want to be able to keep the core logic if possible and I do not want to change this in a way that creates all parent folders first, and then goes back to create subfolders. Instead I want to go down the deepest level, create those folders, then back up to parents. I think this code represents that idea, if I'm making sense.

```
foreach (DataRow r in dtParentFolders.Rows) // these are the 3 parent rows with null pid
{                
    int parentFolderId = Convert.ToInt32(r["id"]);
    string parentFolderName = r["folder_name"].ToString();

    //Create folder
    Console.WriteLine(parentFolderName);

    DataTable dt = GetFolders(parentFolderId);

    foreach (DataRow r2 in dt.Rows)
    {
        parentFolderId = Convert.ToInt32(r2["id"]);
        CreateFolder(r2);
        dt = GetFolders(parentFolderId);

        foreach (DataRow r3 in dt.Rows)
        {
            parentFolderId = Convert.ToInt32(r3["id"]);
            CreateFolder(r3);
            dt = GetFolders(parentFolderId);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So the question here is how to create CRUD procedures to maintain your directory table?

Comment: have you considered a tagging structure, where an item is in multiple categories instead?  might improve the experience

Comment: @SteveC No I'm asking how to rewrite the logic so it can handle x number of different folder/subfolders structures. The number subfolder levels can change. My logic only goes down 3 levels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this can help you in some way.

```
    public class Record
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int PId { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    

    public static void Main()
    {
        var records = new List<Record>() 
        { 
            new Record { Id = 1,    Name = "MainDir1",      PId = 0 },
            new Record { Id = 2,    Name = "MainDir2",      PId = 0 },
            new Record { Id = 3,    Name = "MainDir3",      PId = 0 },
            new Record { Id = 4,    Name = "SubDir1",       PId = 1 },
            new Record { Id = 5,    Name = "SubDir2",       PId = 2 },
            new Record { Id = 6,    Name = "SubSubDir1",    PId = 5 },
            new Record { Id = 7,    Name = "SubSubDir2",    PId = 5 },
            new Record { Id = 8,    Name = "SubSubDir3",    PId = 5 },
            new Record { Id = 9,    Name = "SubSubDir4",    PId = 5 },
            new Record { Id = 10,   Name = "SubSubDir5",    PId = 5 },
        };

        var node = new Directory(0, null, null);

        records
            .OrderBy(x => x.PId)
            .ThenBy(x => x.Id)
            .ThenBy(x => x.Name)
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(x => node.AddChild(x.Name, x.Id, x.PId));

        node.Print();
    }



    public class Directory
    {
        public Directory(int id, string name, Directory parent)
        {
            this.Id = id;
            this.Name = name;
            this.Parent = parent;
            this.Indentation = parent is null ? 0 : parent.Indentation + 1;

            this.Children = new HashSet<Directory>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int Indentation { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public Directory Parent { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Directory> Children { get; set; }

        public void AddChild (string name, int id, int parentId)
        {
            if (this.Id == parentId)
            {
                this.Children.Add(new Directory(id, name, this));
                return;
            }

            foreach (var child in this.Children)
            {
                child.AddChild(name, id, parentId);
            }
        }

        public void Print()
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{new string(' ', this.Indentation * 4)}{this.Name}");

            foreach (var child in this.Children)
            {
                child.Print();
            }
        }
    }
```