# C# populate a hierarchy tree from bottom to top

Tags: c#, linq

I have to fill an hierarchy tree starting from bottom to top, starting from a node till its root node:
I have a table with a many to one relation inside, which contains the id of a subordinate and the id of its superior.

```
PK | SUBORDINATE_ID | SUPERIOR_ID
1  |       50       |    22
2  |       51       |    22
3  |       52       |    22
4  |       22       |    10
5  |       10       |     1
6  |       60       |     2
7  |       70       |     3
8  |       80       |     4
```

How can I efficently traverse the table and fill a structure to fit my needs?
Which structure should I use considering that there could be more then one root nodes?

For example 4 Co-founders would be my 4 root nodes but they can be more then 4 in the future

A structure that could fit my needs would be a list of class like this

```
public class HierarchyMember
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<HierarchyMember> Children { get; set; }
}
```

But it's not practical in the usage with LINQ and also it's hard to fill from bottom to top.

Comment: *"I have to fill an hierarchy tree starting from bottom to top"* - can you please clarify this point? What do you mean by "from bottom to top"?

Comment: Whether from the bottom up or back, you will need to sort the data first. See this solution, you can probably adapt it to your needs - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63549674/generating-a-directory-folder-structure-from-database/63550456#63550456

Comment: since many subordinate can have only 1 superior you could first group by the `SUPERIOR_ID` this way you would have all the children in one place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The approach would be something like this:

1. Create a node for each value
2. Add each node as a child to its parent node
3. Find all non root nodes, i.e. all nodes that are children to another node.
4. Find all root nodes, i.e. the inverse of step 3.

Example with some assumptions:

1. The table is given as a list of id and parent-id
2. Roots are marked by having the same id and parent id, replace with whatever is appropriate in your case.

   ```
    public class HierarchyMember
    {
        public int Id { get; }
        public List<HierarchyMember> Children { get; } = new List<HierarchyMember>();
        public HierarchyMember(int id) => Id = id;
    }
    public static IEnumerable<HierarchyMember> BuildTree(List<(int Id, int ParentId)> hierarchy)
    {
        var dictionary = hierarchy.ToDictionary(p => p.Id, p => new HierarchyMember(p.Id));
        foreach (var (id, parentId) in hierarchy)
        {
            if (id != parentId)
            {
                dictionary[parentId].Children.Add(dictionary[id]);
            }
        }

        var nonRoots = dictionary.Values.SelectMany(p => p.Children).ToHashSet();
        var roots = dictionary.Values.Where(p => !nonRoots.Contains(p)).ToList();
        return roots;
    }
   ```